# Improve the tempral complexity of the algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a simple function

```
bool function(int*a,int n)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<=n-1;i++)
    if(a[i]==i)
       return true;
  return false;
}
```

,where `a` is a sorted vector which contains distinct elements and n is the size of the vector.

I need to improve the temporal complexity of this algorithm. My first  thought was to use the binary search but I can figure out how to  make the recursion work in this case. Basically the function check if there is an element in the sorted array for which the index is equal with the element.

Comment: "improve the temporal complexity"? Do you mean "decrease the asymptotic runtime"?

Comment: @duskwuff yes...something like this

Comment: Have you tried changing the compiler optimization settings?

Comment: @duskwuff Now the worst case is `O(n)`.I think that because the array is sorted it must be a logarithmic solution.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews is a theoretical problem.

Comment: Are the array elements unique?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes indeed .I forgot to mention. Sorry for my mistake. I will udate the question.

Comment: Then binary search still works. E.g. if `a[i] < i` for some `i`, then the same is true for all `j < i`.

Comment: @JimMischel I updated the question .The elements are all distinct. There is no duplicates in the array.

Comment: @AlbertoCarp presumably, the array may contain negative elements? Otherwise the answer would be trivial.

Comment: Why don't you use existing `std` functions? Like `find` or `any_of`...

Comment: @JesperJuhl: And how would those functions have to be called? To my knowledge there is no function that returns the index of an element, where the element and index are the same.

Comment: For a given index ask if there is `any_of` that value..

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yeah, well, uhm, right. That's totally going to reduce the time complexity of the algorithm. Oh hey, maybe that is an answer to your question *"Why don't you use existing `std` functions? Like `find` or `any_of`..."* after all. Just in case you missed it: Your proposal does in fact increase the time complexity of the algorithm. Standards compliance is not a quality in and of itself. And being dogmatic about it has the potential to backfire.

Answer (score 3):

Without giving a complete solution, you're on the right track with binary search. Some hints:

The a[i]'s are distinct and increasing *integers*

If a[i] is greater than i at some point, what does that mean for a[j] where j > i? (start with a[i+1] as compared to i+1)

Similarly, if a[i] < i, what does that mean for a[j] for j < i?

Put these facts together. What does this mean for where a[i] "crosses over" i? How do you find where that happens?

Comment: This is a first in years: An answer that tries to teach how to fish (vs. handing out the Filet-O-Fish) that doesn't get instantly down-voted for *"not providing a solution"*. +1 for the *"crossing over"* picture alone.